# Using Distinct in Laravel Fluent

Tags: php, laravel, fluent, laravel-3

I have this join:

```
Return DB::table('volunteer')
            ->join('volunteer_volunteer_category', 'volunteer_volunteer_category.volunteer_id', '=', 'volunteer.id')
            ->select(array('*','volunteer.id AS link_id'))
            ->where('is_published', '=', 1)
```

But it unsurprisingly returns duplicate records, so I try to use `distinct()`:

```
Return DB::table('volunteer')
            ->join('volunteer_volunteer_category', 'volunteer_volunteer_category.volunteer_id', '=', 'volunteer.id')
            ->select(array('*','volunteer.id AS link_id'))
                        ->distinct()
            ->where('is_published', '=', 1)
```

but I want to use `distinct()` *on a specific single field* which I'd easily be able to do in SQL. It seems `distinct()` does not take parameters, i.e. I can't say `distinct('volunteer.id')`.

Can anyone point me to how can I remove my duplicate records? I bet this is another forehead slapper for me.

Comment: Of course I'm being completely stupid here and need to add `->group_by('volunteer.id')` as well as `->distinct()`.

Comment: But including `->group_by('volunteer.id')` makes my pagination links disappear!!???

Comment: I believe that there's been a bug with pagination and group_by for a while now in Laravel 3; I don't know whether it's been resolved in Laravel 4.

Answer (score 26):

In my project I tried `distinct()` and `groupby()` too and both of them worked:

```php
//Distinct version.
Company_Customer_Product::where('Company_id', '=', $companyid)->distinct()->get(array('Customer_id'));
//Goup by version.
Company_Customer_Product::where('Company_id', '=', $companyid)->groupby('Customer_id')->get(array('Customer_id'));
```

According to this, `distinct()` should work in your case too, just use it with `get()`:

```php
Return DB::table('volunteer')
   ->join('volunteer_volunteer_category', 'volunteer_volunteer_category.volunteer_id', '=', 'volunteer.id')
   ->select(array('*','volunteer.id AS link_id'))
   ->distinct()
   ->where('is_published', '=', 1)
   ->get(array('volunteer.id'));
```

Otherwise you don't need `distinct()` when you use `groupby()` so you could just use:

```php
Return DB::table('volunteer')
   ->join('volunteer_volunteer_category', 'volunteer_volunteer_category.volunteer_id', '=', 'volunteer.id')
   ->select(array('*','volunteer.id AS link_id'))
   ->group_by('volunteer.id')
   ->where('is_published', '=', 1)
   ->get(array('volunteer.id'));
```